# Syllabification function for Turkish words

Tags: python, python-3.x, natural-language-processing

I wrote an NLP script for processing Turkish language. Yesterday I added syllabication but I wonder if it could be done better. It is kinda hard-coded, so I would like to know if I can improve it.

Here is the syllabication part.

```
def syllabicate(self, word):
    """
    :param word: The word to be syllabicated
    :return: The syllabicated list that contains syllabs
    """
    word = word.lower()
    syllabs = []
    syllab = ""
    keep_index = 0
    last_was_vowel = False
    next_is_vowel = False

    for let_ind in range(len(word)):
        if let_ind != len(word) - 1:
            if word[let_ind + 1] in self.vowels:
                next_is_vowel = True
            else:
                next_is_vowel = False
        else:
            syllab = word[keep_index:]
            syllabs.append(syllab)
            break

        if next_is_vowel and not last_was_vowel and syllab:
            syllabs.append(syllab)
            syllab = ""
            keep_index = let_ind

        elif next_is_vowel and word[let_ind] not in self.vowels and syllab:
            syllabs.append(syllab)
            syllab = ""
            keep_index = let_ind

        syllab += word[let_ind]

        if word[let_ind] in self.vowels:
            last_was_vowel = True
        else:
            last_was_vowel = False

    return syllabs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>First of all you should know that the script doesn't syllabize properly for every word. For example if you give the word **authenticated** the function returns **['aut', 'hen', 'ti', 'ca', 'ted']** which is incorrect. The correct case would be **['au','then','ti','cat','ed'].** However I do not know how to fix that.</s>

Edit: The point made above doesn't stand since this script isn't for the english language.

Second you have a lot of *ifs* where you check if a character is a vowel like this:

```
if word[let_ind] in self.vowels:
        last_was_vowel = True
    else:
        last_was_vowel = False
```

They could be written better like this:

```
last_was_vowel = word[let_ind] in self.vowels
```

Or even better I would have written a function that checks if a letter is a vowel.

```
def is_vowel(self, char):
    return char in self.vowels
```

The first *if* in your for loop

```
if let_ind != len(word) - 1:
    if word[let_ind + 1] in self.vowels:
        next_is_vowel = True
    else:
        next_is_vowel = False
else:
    syllab = word[keep_index:]
    syllabs.append(syllab)
    break
```

checks if the next one is a vowel except the last char.
It would be more good looking like this:

```
for pos, char in enumerate(word[:-1]):
    next_is_vowel = self.is_vowel(word[pos + 1])
    ...

syllab = word[keep_index:]
syllabs.append(syllab)
```

We enumerate through the word to get the position of the letter and 
the letter itself. The **word[:-1]** means we are going to iterate the whole word except its last letter.

Lastly you got 2 *ifs* here that do the same thing. You also don't need the keep_index.

```
if next_is_vowel and not last_was_vowel and syllab:
    syllabs.append(syllab)
    syllab = ""

elif next_is_vowel and word[let_ind] not in self.vowels and syllab:
    syllabs.append(syllab)
    syllab = ""
```

The could be easily written as one *if* like this:

```
if next_is_vowel and syllab and not (last_was_vowel and self.is_vowel(char)):
    syllabs.append(syllab)
    syllab = ""
```

The place where the keep index was used can be replaced like this
from `syllab = word[keep_index:]`  to `syllab += word[-1]`

With these changes in mind the code looks now like this.

```
def is_vowel(self, char):
    """

    :param char: the character to check
    :return: bool depending if the char is a vowel
    """
    return char in self.vowels

def syllabicate(self, word):
    """
    :param word: The word to be syllabicated
    :return: The syllabicated list that contains syllabs
    """
    word = word.lower()
    syllabs = []
    syllab = ""
    last_was_vowel = False
    # we don't want the last character

    for pos, char in enumerate(word[:-1]):
        next_is_vowel = self.is_vowel(word[pos + 1])

        if next_is_vowel and syllab and not (last_was_vowel and self.is_vowel(char)):

            syllabs.append(syllab)
            syllab = ""

        syllab += char
        last_was_vowel = self.is_vowel(char)

    syllab += word[-1]
    syllabs.append(syllab)

    return syllabs
```

Comment: As I mentioned it is for Turkish language only since every language has its own rules it is not going to work for English. And thanks a lot for the advices, they are totally on point.

Comment: Oh I am sorry about that. I will remove that part then from the post since it doesn't offer anything constructive.